# Вырезать комментарий

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток! делаю минимизатор js файлов и столкнулся с проблемой - регулярка:

```
/\/\*(.*)\*\//s
```

не вырезает комментарии вида:

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v2.0.3
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2013-07-03T13:30Z
 */
```

что не так?

Comment: вам заняться больше нечем ?

Comment: @woland

    <?php
    $a = <<<EOT
    bla-bla-bla
    /*!
     * jQuery JavaScript Library v2.0.3
     * http://jquery.com/
     *
     * Includes Sizzle.js
     * http://sizzlejs.com/
     *
     * Copyright 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
     * Released under the MIT license
     * http://jquery.org/license
     *
     * Date: 2013-07-03T13:30Z
     */
    bla-bla-bla
    EOT;
    $b = preg_replace('/\/\*(.*)\*\//sm', '', $a);
    echo $b;

результат:

    bla-bla-bla

    bla-bla-bla

Comment: парсить исходники регекспами - это ещё круче чем парсить ими же HTML. сложно сказать что не так, если всё настолько чудесно.

Comment: @alexlz http://ideone.com/cZ7Tox

Comment: @alexlz,

    /*
      parsing of "/* ... */" failed
    */
    alert( 'parsing of "/* ... */" failed' );

Comment: @klopp согласен, с вложенными комментариями регекспами справиться трудно

@eicto там то что не так? Или это вопрос на тему "не будь жадиной"? Так не будьте

     $b = preg_replace('/\/\*(.*?)\*\//sm', '', $a);

Comment: @woland, а о **строковых константах** такого вида

    "/* comment */ other text:"

в программе Вы уже подумали?

Comment: @alexlz, в моём примере нет вложенных комментариев.

Comment: @alexlz я собственно тоже о строках. Воообще наверное придется повторить мысль - делать минимизатор - ненужная затея, а делать его на регекспах еще и мазохизм граничащий с идиотизмом.

Comment: @eicto, идея-то как раз шикарная, с точки зрения самообразования. столько нового и интересного можно узнать, вникая в устройство парсеров :) Заодно и с парой-другой ЯП если не освоишь, то хоть познакомишься. Но соглашусь, "пожать регекспами" сводит всю гипотетическую пользу от этого занятия даже не в ноль, а в глубокий минус.

Comment: а как лучше? если не регекспами?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы воспользовался этим выражением:

```
/(\/\*.*?\*\/)/s
```

***Что бы получать комментарии:***

```
$jsComment = <<<COMMENT
   /*!
    * jQuery JavaScript Library v2.0.3
    * http://jquery.com/
    *
    * Includes Sizzle.js
    * http://sizzlejs.com/
    *
    * Copyright 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
    * Released under the MIT license
    * http://jquery.org/license
    *
    * Date: 2013-07-03T13:30Z
    */
    /*
        other test comments
     */
COMMENT;

$regExp = "/(\/\*.*?\*\/)/s";
preg_match_all($regExp,$jsComment,$result);
print_r($result[0][0]);
```

***Зачистить значение переменной, от  js комментариев:***

```
$result = preg_replace($regExp,"",$jsComment)
```

***Что бы зачистить файл JS, от комментариев:***

```
$jsFile = file_get_contents("file.js");

file_put_contents("newFile.js",preg_replace($regExp,"",$jsFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

надо в скрипте при детектировании во входной строке символов **/*!** заходить в цикл и удалять все строки до ***/**. А их выделить из строки несложно :

```
/^\/\*!/s  и /^\*\//s
```

а в одной строке надо делать так :

```
/(^\/\*!)|(^\*\/)|(^\*)/s
```